# Bind selected option from drop down to Typesscript object Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form where users can create Todo's. An `ITodo` has the following properties:

```
export interface ITodo {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    priority: ITodoPriority;
}
export interface ITodoPriority {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

So creating a Todo consists of setting the `title`-property and selecting a `priority` from a dropdown. The form looks like this:

```
<form (submit)="saveTodo()">
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="todo.title" />
    <br />
    <select (change)="setPriority($event.target.value)">
        <option *ngFor="let priority of formModel.priorities" [value]="priority" [innerHtml]="priority.name"></option>
    </select>
</form>
```

And my `Component`:

```
@Component({
    selector: "[todo-form]",
    templateUrl: "todo-form.view.html"
})
export class TodoFormComponent implements OnInit {
    private formModel: ITodoFormModel;
    private todo: ITodo = {
        id: -1,
        name: "",
        priority: null
    };

    ngOnInit() {
        //Retrieve formmodel, set in actual code
    }

    private setPriority(priority: any): void {
        this.todo.priority = priority; //This is where the problems is
    }
}
```

The problem is in the function `setPriority` and specifically at the part where I try to set `this.todo.priority`. The value of the parameter `priority` is available but I'm unable to set it to `this.todo.priority`.
What I have tried, and what does work is the following:

```
private setPriority(priority: any): void {
    let p: ITodoPriority = null;
    this.formModel.priorities.forEach(function (item) {
        if(priority == item) {
            p = item;
        }
    });
    this.todo.priority = p;
}
```

So, this does work but it's a bit ugly and inefficient it seems.
What would be the way to do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not also use two-way-binding with the `priority`? Also since you are using a form, I'm surprised it doesn't throw you error by not using `name`-attribute in your form, but anyway, use two-way-binding, and since `priority` is an object, and you want to bind the whole object, use `[ngValue]`. So your select would look like this:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="todo.priority" name="priority" >
  <option *ngFor="let priority of formModel.priorities" [ngValue]="priority">
      {{priority.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

So no change event is needed here since you are using two-way-binding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
<select (ngModelChange)="setPriority($event)">
        <option *ngFor="let priority of formModel.priorities" [value]="priority" >{{priority.name}}</option>
</select>
```

If it doesnt work can you please tell the value of the object you receive on change

```
private setPriority(priority: any): void {
    this.todo.priority = priority; //Is this value you are receiving correct?
}
```